# Increment in a loop

Tags: python

Hello i'm trying to increment a parameter in my loop but it seems does not work correctly. Python just consider my first loop with Cp=1:

```
Cp=0
track=2
variable=np.arange(track,1,6)
a=np.zeros(shape=(3,2))

    for track in variable:
        Cp=+1

        if Cp==1:
             eps=0.0

        elif Cp==2:
             eps=a(Cp-1,2)/2*3.14*track
             tau=a(Cp-1,2)
             print tau

        else:
        eps=0.003
```

The second loop where Cp==2 is never took into account?? So how incrementing Cp??
The other problem i have is that my empty array a can't be filled since i got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 35, in <module>
    eps_real=a(Cp-0.5,2)/2*3.14*track
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Any idea?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: In python, you need to write `a[i]` instead of `a(i)`.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't using the correct compound operator. You want `+=` instead of `=+`

```
>>> cp = 1
>>> cp +=1
>>> cp
2
>>> cp =+1
>>> cp
1
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `+=` operator. `Cp=+1` only assigns 1 to Cp.

You can achieve increment via two common ways:

```
>>> cp = 0
>>> cp = cp + 1
>>> print cp
1
>>> cp += 1
>>> print cp
2
```

By the way please do not start variables with capital letter. The class names usually starts with capital letter. If you have two word variable then use camel case naming. For example if you would like to give my good variable name to a variable use `myGoodVariable`. For my good class use `MyGoodClass`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to write `Cp=Cp+1` or `Cp+=1` instead of `Cp=+1` !

Answer (score 0):

Beside the already mentioned, you should consider using the [enumerate()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) builtin.

```
for i, item in enumerate(L):
    # ... compute some result based on item ...
    L[i] = result
```

Taken from PEP279.